# SQL: How to use linear regression or regr_slope() in sliding window frame?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following code to generate an example table.

```
create or replace table aggr(ACCT_ID NUMBER(18,0), YYYYMMDD NUMBER(18,0), value NUMBER(10, 2));
insert into aggr values(1,0, 0);
insert into aggr values(1,30, 90);
insert into aggr values(1,60, 60);
insert into aggr values(1,90, 90);
insert into aggr values(2,0, 0);
insert into aggr values(2,30, 90);
insert into aggr values(2,60, 60);
insert into aggr values(2,90, 90);
```

What I want to achieve is for each `acc_id`, the `regr_slope(y, x)` can be computed for every row given the preceding two rows and current row where `x = YYYYMMDD` and `y = value`. In this case for `acct_id=1`,  for the first two rows for every account, since it doesn't have two preceding rows, it will return `NULL`. The third row, `regr_slope()` will use row1,row2,row3 to get the output.

Then I tried to use the following code but it fails

```
SELECT
      regr_slope(value, YYYYMMDD) over (PARTITION BY acct_id order by YYYYMMDD rows between 
2 preceding and current row) as avg_3mo_hist
FROM
    aggr
```

I received the following error:

```
SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 79 Sliding window frame unsupported for function REGR_SLOPE
```

According to [snowflake documentations](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regr_slope.html#usage-notes), it says for `regr_slope()`

```
When used as a window function: 
    This function does not support:

    - ORDER BY sub-clause in the OVER() clause.

    - Window frames.
```

I tried so many different ways but none works. Would like to know how to achieve the goal with `regr_slope()` function

Comment: Keep on dbms tag, the one for the dbms actually used. Remove the rest of them.

Comment: As you seem to be using the Snowflake platform, I removed the conflicting tags for Postgres and SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using window functions to get "3 months previous" is not a safe operation, because if a month is missing then suddenly you are covering 4, 5 or more months.

Instead, you can solve the 3 previous month aggregation with a self join:

```sql
SELECT
      a.ACCT_ID, a.YYYYMMDD, ARRAY_AGG(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(b.value, b.YYYYMMDD)) arragg
      -- over (PARTITION BY acct_id order by YYYYMMDD rows between 2 preceding and current row) as avg_3mo_hist
FROM aggr a
JOIN aggr b
ON a.acct_id=b.acct_id
-- replace with real dates and date math
AND a.YYYYMMDD BETWEEN b.YYYYMMDD AND b.YYYYMMDD+90 
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

[image]

With that data in hand, now it's easy to get the desired 3 month slope:

```sql
WITH window_90_day
AS (
    SELECT
          a.ACCT_ID, a.YYYYMMDD, ARRAY_AGG(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(b.value, b.YYYYMMDD)) arragg
    FROM aggr a
    JOIN aggr b
    ON a.acct_id=b.acct_id
    -- replace with real dates and date math
    AND a.YYYYMMDD BETWEEN b.YYYYMMDD AND b.YYYYMMDD+90 
    GROUP BY 1, 2
)

SELECT ACCT_ID, YYYYMMDD
  , regr_slope(x.value[0], x.value[1]) slope
FROM window_90_day, table(flatten(arragg)) x
GROUP BY 1,2
```

[image]

Comment: why do you use `array` and `array_agg`?

Comment: `array_construct`: to hold both value and date, `array_agg`: to collect all 90 day previous values and dates